# Xcode 10 runs really slow and slows my entire computer down

Tags: imac, xcode

I'm currently using Xcode 10.1 and it's driving me crazy, it slows my computer down to a point that it is unusable. Before I upgraded to Xcode 10 I was running the same project on Xcode 9 and High Sierra without any problems and with only half of the memory it currently has (8GB of Ram). I now have upgraded the memory to 16GB but it didn't make a difference.

FYI - I don't think the slow down has to do with Mojave 10.14.2 since I was experiencing the same issue with High Sierra and Xcode 10, which is the reason I upgraded to Mojave thinking that Xcode 10 would run smoother in the newest operating system.

### Here are the specs of my computer:

Computer has a fusion drive.

[image: screenshot of computer specs]

### Here is what I see in Activity Monitor for CPU and Memory usage:

[image: screenshot of activity monitor CPU tab]
[image: screenshot of activity monitor memory tab]

### Disk Activity

[image: Screenshot of activity monitor disk tab]

Any idea what could be wrong?

**EDIT:**
The Simulator may be the possible cause.

In the comments below I stated that the issue was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode but I later found out that it wasn't true. The issue seems to be caused by the Simulator, what I noticed is that if I reboot my computer and don't use the Simulator, Xcode runs fine. But as soon as I use the Simulator, Xcode starts running slow even after closing the Simulator. I need to reboot and use Xcode without using the Simulator to temporarily fix the issue. I have been using hardware-devices for testing and Xcode seem to be running fine. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it doesn’t look as if Xcode is to blame, at least not based on the screenshots above. Can you provide the same screenshots from a moment where the system is close to unusable (take a picture with a smartphone if the system is too slow for screenshots)?

Comment: These screenshots were taken when the system was running  slow. I’m just blaming XCode because if I close it everything starts running fine.

Comment: The system is 91% idle, there is no memory pressure (and hardly any swapping). If it's slow it's coming from something else. I assume you don't have an SSD in a 2012 iMac, what kind of disk activity is going on in such moments?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the Disc Activity. The computer has a Fusion Drive.

Comment: Thanks, looking at it right now, and still wondering. None of the screenshots reflects the slowness you are describing. Speaking of which: what does "close to unusable" mean for you specifically?

Comment: If I click any where in Xcode or any other application there is a 2 or 3 seconds delay, or just typing or moving the mouse. FYI - As soon as I close XCode everyting runs fast.

Comment: I will uninstall and reinstall XCode to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Just for the record, I uninstalled and reinstalled XCode and so far it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: FYI - I later found out that uninstalled and reinstalled XCode did not fix the issue, the Simulator seems to be the cause, see my edited question. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: Have the same problem too.... suddenly the simulator is very very slow, impossible to work with and it stuck all my computer....do you have some big array in your project?

Comment: I do have a big array but I don’t think that’s the problem since I get the slowdown even with new empty projects. My workaround is basically not to use the simulator until apple fixes it.

Comment: I have the same issue. Using the simulator leaves the whole system almost unusable until you reboot. Reinstalling xCode doesn't solve it. Looking at the used system resources yields no information about what's causing it. I'm on a 6700k 16GB ram rig so it should run perfectly

Comment: @FernandoMazzon The only workaround at the moment is to not use the simulator and use hardware devices instead. I just hope Apple fixes it soon.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can confirm it is caused by XCode as it does not happen as long as I do not open XCode, my computer is a Macbook pro High Sierra (not possible to upgrade it further) and XCode version 10.3 (I found out to install this version which is not supposed to work with my os but 10.1 was working even worst)

Comment: Anyone every figure out what the problem was? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same issue - unlike many other posts on the Web, I only have one view controller with a couple of slides and views, so simplifying is not a solution for me -

I suspect the simulator seems to slow things down - there is a SimStreamProcessorService which seems to take a lot of CPU time (look at Activity Monitor under %CPU) -

I restarted XCode and didn't use the simulator and it seems to be running fine.  I have a MacBookPro late 2011 with 16GB RAM running Sierra -

Comment: As I stated in my Edited question: For me restarting XCode doesn't fix the issue, I need to reboot my computer and use XCode without using the Simulator. What I have been doing as a workaround is using my iPhone for testing and XCode runs fine.